# html page loading from js file does not run on server from eclipse

Tags: javascript, html, eclipse

Assuming developing a simple page just to display the clock

I have 2 files

1- html file 
 2-js file

They are the following:

test.js

```js
function init()
 {
  window.onload = displayTime;
  
  }
 function displayTime() 
 {
   var today = new Date();
   var hours = today.getHours();
   var minutes = today.getMinutes();
   var seconds = today.getSeconds();
   hours = formatTime(hours);
   minutes = formatTime(minutes);
   seconds = formatTime(seconds);
   document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
   var t = setTimeout(displayTime, 1000);
 }
function formatTime(i) 
 { //To format time to be like 01:01:01 instead of 1:1:1
    if (i < 10)
     {
      i = "0" + i;
     }
     return i;
  }
```

testTime.html

```html
<head>
 
 <script src="WEB-INF/test.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
init();
</script>
 
 </head> 
<body> 
  <div id="clock"></div> 
</body>
```

Both files are parts of a dynamic web project in eclipse

When I try running testTime.html on server from eclipse, it shows a blank page
[ I tried on JBOSS and on Tomcat]

But when I try clicking on testTime.html in the project folder and launching it directly on broswer, it runs and shows the clock as it's supposed to show!
[image]

Does anyone have an explanation for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contents of `WEB-INF` are not served to clients. Your `web.xml` file is in there. Your application's own classes are in there. Who knows what `.properties` files, passwords, and server information is in there.

Put your JavaScript and HTML files outside of the `WEB-INF` folder.

Comment: **It's working now.** So, when running the html page in any browser by clicking on it, it deals with `WEB-INF` folder as a normal folder on my hard disk, but when running it from eclipse it can't deal with it as a normal folder to clients. Is what I understood right?

Comment: It's the difference between it being served by a server (that happens to have been started by Eclipse) and just opening a file on your hard drive.